# How to split the content of a String into a List

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate a txt file with java , I have the following code ,Firstly I read the txt file withouth any problem , then I add the lines that I am interested at the list called records and this arrays iterate correctly with the while.

The problem is that I received the content like this

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            PCB:0             LISTENING
```

I would like to split this content and avoid the white space  try before with split and trim but I am not doing this correctly.

Could anyone helps to me ?

```
 String FILENAME = "src/example.txt";
        String line = null;
    Integer lines=0;
    Integer totalLines=countLines(FILENAME);
    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{
        InputStream fis=new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lines++;
                if (lines >= 5 && lines <= 180) {
                    records.add(line);
                }
            }
            br.close();

    }


    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: Target File Cannot Be Read");
    }

    Iterator<String> it = records.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println(it.next());

    }
```

Regards !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break your `String` into tokens, delimited by spaces

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
```

Then extract out the individual parts

```
 String substringA = st.nextElement(); // "TCP"
 String substringB = st.nextElement(); // "0.0.0.0:135"
 String substringC = st.nextElement(); // "PCB:0"
 String substringD = st.nextElement(); // "LISTENING"
```

As `StringTokenizer` is hated by many, you can alternatively split it into an array of `String`s delimited by multiple spaces (using the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `"\\s+"`) using a method on the `String` object called [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) like so:-

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
```

and access them via

```
String substringA = tokens[0]; // "TCP"
String substringB = tokens[1]; // "0.0.0.0:135"
String substringC = tokens[2]; // "PCB:0"
String substringD = tokens[3]; // "LISTENING"
```

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**

First of all replace more than one white spaces with single white space -

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

Than, split it by space,

```
String[] lineTokens = line.split(" ");
```

**Method 2**

As David has suggested, you can do like this too -

```
String[] lineTokens = line.split("\\s+");
```

Hope this will help you ;)

Comment: `line.split("\\s+")` does it in one go; `split` already takes a regex.